# How do I allow local IPv6 subnets in ufw?

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw

I recently got IPv6 connectivity at home and now I would like to allow connections to my home server via IPv6 from the LAN only. The trick is that the IPv6 address/prefix assigned to the server is dynamic. Is there some way to write a UFW rule that allows only from directly connected subnets?

Comment: Keep in mind there are no IPv6 "local ranges" - each IPv6 local range is going to be different all the time and there is no way to accept them all.  You would need to add a UFW rule that would be for each individual subnet - if that subnet is always changing then you can't reliably create a firewall rule in any setup that can do what you're looking to accomplish.

Answer (score 7):

Keep in mind there are no IPv6 "local ranges" - each IPv6 "local range" is its own (at least) /64 segment of v6 addresses in a specifically defined prefix.  As such, any 'private range' address you receive is going to be specific to the subnet your router sets you up on rather than the external v6 address you have (there's logic inside routers to set up the subnets automatically, but when you get into Enterprise-grade routing with advanced firewalls, routers, switches, etc., IPv6 has to be manually configured by hand and set up.

When you add into the equation that you will quite possibly (and frequently) have a changing subnet all the time, there is no way to accept them all dynamically without accepting all IPv6 inbound connections - at least on a consumer-grade network setup (with a much-more-complicated and much-more-expensive firewall appliance, you can explicitly do VLAN separation to prevent things from communicating with the outside and accept only internal v6, but you can't do this on consumer-grade router technologies).

As well, firewall rules are designed in `ufw` (and the underlying `iptables` and `netfilter` technologies which ufw works with) to have *specific* rules (such as `ALLOW aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::dead:beef INBOUND TO dddd:eeee:ffff:0000::dead:beef PORT 22/tcp` (obviously not a rule, but just an example)) and if you are always having different addresses on different v6 subnets, (either internally or externally, but especially internally), it breaks the requirements that firewalls have for those kinds of rules.

You would therefore need to know all the subnets you'll get, and add a `ufw` rule that would be for each individual subnet.  If that subnet is always changing and you do not know which subnet you will get, then you can't reliably create a firewall rule in any setup that can do what you're looking to accomplish on a dynamic ever-changing basis.

This also applies to port-forwarding at home - you can't reliably set up a port forward UNLESS the internal IP address (v4 or v6) isn't going to change.  (The router transparently handles INBOUND from the internet, on its own, so long as you set up the internal v6 in a static setup, but you can't guarantee this will happen without much more time-consuming network configuration and setups, and possibly more enterprise-grade level equipment which can get expensive)

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm looking for is something more along the lines of what the Windows firewall offers. It lets you specify that you want to allow the [Local Subnet(s) only](https://i.imgur.com/m902JPe.png).

Comment: @user96232 What that is doing is that it would only permit whatever CIDR range is on the dynamically assigned IPv6 address - that is, if you get the IP address of 1111:2222:3333::3652/64, anything in the /64 would be considered the 'local range' but still be a public IP address.  Unless you are *explicitly* setting your network DHCP with a private IPv6 address prefix (such as those generated by [this tool](http://simpledns.com/private-ipv6.aspx)), which are actually not addressable in the public Internet and then setting up IPv6 (sorta)NAT, you're not going to have a 'local ipv6 subnet'.

Comment: "it would only permit whatever CIDR range is on the dynamically assigned IPv6 address "


That's precisely the goal. The router does not allow traffic from the public internet, but I want the clients on the subnet to communicate. I realize that I can rely on the router and use an allow any rule on the hosts, but I was hoping ufw had something smarter than that.

Comment: Not getting it. Is FE80::/64 not a local-subnet only mask?

Comment: @RobinDavies it's a link-local range.  It only exists on that link.  Every system *theoretically* gives itself a link-local fe80::/64 range, but if you're running a firewall you still have to *accept* the traffic on that.  HOWEVER, it is *not* addressable from a router.  It literally only exists as link-local, and routers can't route data *to* it properly.  Actual v6 forwarding requires an *actual* IPv6 address whether it is assigned from the router with an actual public IPv6 address or from the router with a local network within the `fc00::/7` range space.

Answer (score 7):

Old question, but Google got me here so I think it's worth noting that you could add the IPv6 link-local range with:

```
ufw allow from fe80::/64
```

If you're connecting across the LAN then the link-local address should get used instead of your global IPv6 address.

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm looking for is something more along the lines of what the Windows firewall offers. It lets you specify that you want to allow the [Local Subnet(s) only](https://i.imgur.com/m902JPe.png).

Comment: @user96232 There's no equivalency between hte "Local subnets only" option and anywhere else, not without a lot of manual definitions.

Comment: What is "local subnets"?
There are basically two major types of IPv6 addresses to consider.  `FE80::/64` for link local addresses, which is only useful within your LAN.  `2000::/3` (that is an address that starts with a `2` or `3`) for global addresses.  Which is used when you want to reach outside of your LAN.  And no private address like `10.0.0.0/8` or `192.168.0.0/16` in IPv4.