# How to configure VSFTPD for LAN-only access, and restrict the access to a single directory

Tags: vsftpd

I have gone through quite a few setup guides but couldn't figure out, how to configure VSFTPD for LAN-only access, and restrict the access to a single directory (e.g.: ~/Downloads).

If possible, I do not even want to expose its presence to the Internet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

PC: Ubuntu Mate 19.04 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks alot. I still need help with Firewall rules but I got (1) Restricting access to a single directory, and (2) Securing transactions from the DigitalOcean article. Though I have not applied any of the Firewall rules detailed in the article as those rules may enable FTP access from the Internet. I did test FTP access in my own Terminal, and it's working, before and after applying TLS/SSL cert.

Comment: I will try the exact syntax and write a full answer.

Comment: @user68186 Thank you so much. Please post an answer with firewall-rules syntax, and DigitalOcean article link (so it can help anyone that comes across). I kinda know, how to add simple firewall rules. I just don't know how to allow FTP traffic from LAN while blocking access outside my LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## LAN-Only Access

This is best done with firewall rules. We will use `ufw` the **uncomplicated firewall** for this.

First we check the status of `ufw`

```
sudo ufw status
```

If you see `Status: inactive` then use the following command to enable `ufw`:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

As described in the link below we will allow ports 20 and 21 for the basic VSFTPD access. We will not use the simple ufw rule like:

```
sudo ufw allow ftp
```

as this will allow access from everywhere. To allow LAN-Only access we will use advance syntax:

```
sudo ufw allow  from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 20 proto tcp
sudo ufw allow  from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 21 proto tcp
```

The `from 192.168.0.0/24` is the LAN-Only part. Yours may be different. Some home routers assign IP addresses in the range 192.168.0.x, and others in the range 192.168.1.x, where x is between 2-255. The `/24` subnet mask says any value of x in that range is allowed.

The `to any` means any IP address assigned to this computer is okay. Since this computer is not acting as a router, this setting is okay.

The `port 20` (or `21`) is the port this rule opens.

The `proto tcp` is the only `tcp` protocol (not the `udp` protocol) can be used.

If we want to add the ports 990, and 40,000 to 50,000 ports to the firewall as in the tutorial below, we can use one command to do that:

```
sudo ufw allow  from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 990,40000:50000 proto tcp
```

#### A Note about IPv6

I don't know enough about IPv6 local addresses and subnet masks to write an answer that includes IPv6 ufw rules. Without any Ipv6 *allow* rules any attempt to use IPv6 addresses to access the `ftp` site will be denied.

The answers to this question suggests there may not be an easy solution for IPv6: [How do I allow local IPv6 subnets in ufw?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285679/how-do-i-allow-local-ipv6-subnets-in-ufw)

For what it is worth, the following allow rule syntax (based on an answer to the above question) is accepted by `ufw`:

```
sudo ufw allow  from fe80::/64 to any port 21 proto tcp
```

This should allow ftp access from the link-local IPv6 range that start with `fe80`.

## Restrict user to a single directory

This is very well described in the [Digital Ocean Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04). The main steps are reproduced below:

In this example the username is `sammy`. The basic concept is the user `sammy` **must not have write access** to the base directory of the user-accessible directory. Create the `ftp` folder, set its ownership, and be sure to remove write permissions with the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /home/sammy/ftp
sudo chown nobody:nogroup /home/sammy/ftp
sudo chmod a-w /home/sammy/ftp
```

Next, we create the directory where files can be uploaded and assign ownership to the user:

```
sudo mkdir /home/sammy/ftp/files
sudo chown sammy:sammy /home/sammy/ftp/files
```

Next we edit the VSFTPD configuration file in nano:

```
sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

and make the following changes / additions:

```
. . .
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default).
anonymous_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
. . .
write_enable=YES
. . .
chroot_local_user=YES
. . .
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
. . .
```

When we are done making the change, save and exit the file.

Then, we create and add our user to the file. We’ll use the -a flag to append to file:

```
echo "sammy" | sudo tee -a /etc/vsftpd.userlist
```

Funally we restart the daemon to load the configuration changes:

```
sudo systemctl restart vsftpd
```

Hope this helps

Comment: last question: can I add rules for port 990 and for a port-range 40000:50000 too in similar manner?: sudo ufw allow  from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 990 proto tcp
sudo ufw allow  from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 40000:50000 proto tcp

Comment: Many thanks, and though I'm not concerned about IPv6 right now, but for future reference, how would I add the same four rules for IPv6 too.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I have tested the syntax of the new commands.

Comment: Earlier I tested the complete VsFTPD setup within my LAN (from Ubuntu Mate 19.04 to Debian 10), and it's working great. I got the IPv6 part and updated ufw command. Thank you so much.